# How to insert HTML with inline css styles and render using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, appendchild

I'm trying to add HTML code with inline CSS styles and to render into HTML page using JS:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.innerHTML =
    "   <article id='sp-shop-offer' dir='ltr' style='bottom: 0px;width: 100%;height: 100%;left: 0px;z-index: 10000000;letter-spacing: 0;font-family: 'Open Sans'" sans-serif;font-weight: 400;font-size: 12px;color: white;position: fixed;overflow: hidden;'>  "  + 
 /// ETC etc etc
 "           </div>  "  + 
 "       </section>  "  + 
 "  </article>  ";

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

when I run this code its added to HTML page but seems wthout all css styles.

How to add my HTML code with inline css styles and to render using javascript?

Comment: You can try using jquery

Answer (score 2):

You have some syntax errors inside and style attribute, use this:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.innerHTML =
    "   <article id='sp-shop-offer' dir='ltr' style='bottom: 0px;width: 100%;height: 100%;left: 0px;z-index: 10000000;letter-spacing: 0;font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;font-weight: 400;font-size: 12px;color: white;position: fixed;overflow: hidden;'>  "  + 
 /// ETC etc etc
 "           </div>  "  + 
 "       </section>  "  + 
 "  </article>  ";

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Template literals maybe better and it causes to reduce your error

```
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.innerHTML =
    `   <article id='sp-shop-offer' dir='ltr' style='bottom: 0px;width: 100%;height: 100%;left: 0px;z-index: 10000000;letter-spacing: 0;font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;font-weight: 400;font-size: 12px;color: white;position: fixed;overflow: hidden;'>  

          </div>  
       </section>  
   </article>  `;

document.body.appendChild(div);
```